# Exception when passing list object as table valued parameter in C# asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2008

I have a `List<>` object which I have to pass to a stored procedure in SQL Server 2008 as a table valued parameter. Here is the code:

```
List<someType> listObjects = new List<someType>();
//Fill listObjects
...
...
...
sqlcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@myTableValuedParameter",listObjects).SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Structured;
sqlcmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Code is throwing an exception which says:

> Object must implement IConvertible.

In past,I have successfully passed a `DataTable`  as a table valued parameter.
Structure of type of `object` `someType` is same as custom Type which I created in Sql Server.

What am I missing here and what changes do I need to include to make it run sucessfully

Comment: convert your list<> to type DataTable? as they are different stuff.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 3 things that can be passed as a Table Value Parameter:

- `IEnumerable<SqlDataRecord>`
- `DataTable`
- `DbDataReader`

Your list, unless it contains `SqlDataRecord` cannot be used

[Table-Valued Parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb675163%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

> System.Data.SqlClient supports populating table-valued parameters from DataTable, DbDataReader or System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable ([T:System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1)] objects.

Answer (score 0):

Per the [Table-Valued Parameters documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb675163.aspx) only `DataTable`, `DbDataReader` or `IEnumerable<SqlDataRecord>` are supported:

> System.Data.SqlClient supports populating table-valued parameters from DataTable, DbDataReader or System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable